# Trying to call find_by_id on ActiveRecord::Relation, Arel exception

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I'm getting to grips with Rails 3 and I can't seem to do a basic find from a result set. My code looks like the following:

```
@project = 
   @user.where({:projects => {:project_member_id => user.id}}).find_by_id(params[:id])
```

I understand that the "where" section will not return a collection but merely create a query that is waiting to be run against the db. However, I can't understand why I get the following error when I try to run the find_by_id:

```
undefined method `to_sql' for #<Arel::Attributes::String:0x106d9ecf0>
```

Can somebody point out where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: What happens if you just run: `.find(params[:id])` ?

Comment: Same exception I'm afraid....

Answer (score 0):

May be you can write something like this:

```
@project = 
   @user.where({:projects => {:project_member_id => user.id}}).where(:id => params[:id])
```

I think it will works.

Alex.

Comment: This still returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object and not the actual object I'm afraid...

Comment: You can use `.first` with above answer that will return single actual object  rather then  ActiveRecord::Relation object.

Answer (score 0):

I could be misunderstanding what you are trying to do here, but it looks like you have an association called `projects` in the user model, right?  If so, this is much simpler (and works):

```
@project = @user.projects.find params[:id]
```

If you don't have an association setup, you should look into them.  There is a great rails guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on the subject.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Afraid I've removed some of the logic here for brevity's sake so this doesnt work - sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned above, "where" would return ActiveRecord::Relation object, you can check it by running:

```
@project = 
   @user.where({:projects => {:project_member_id => user.id}}).class
```

In order to return a collection of instantiated objects and run find, you can try to force it by running something like:

```
@project = 
   @user.where({:projects => {:project_member_id => user.id}}).all.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Love method chaining in Rails!

However, this would first find all projects with passed uesr.id (which can be costly, and, probably not what you want)...

Good luck!

Comment: Strange - this is throwing the following exception: undefined method `find_by_id' for #<Array:0x106d3fd40>

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@project = 
   @user.where({:projects => {:project_member_id => user.id}}).where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

But I dont understand why you are doing all these when you have the primary key with you..just `Model.find params[:id]` is enough I think (I assume there is something more to it).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@project = @user.where({:projects => {:project_member_id => user.id}}).all.find {|p| p.id == params[:id]}
```

Comment: I beleive u meant `find_all` or `select` in place of `find`, but this will not append to the sql query, but run the first query, take the collection and select from the array satisfying the condition from the ruby code and not in the database level.

Comment: No I did mean `find` because the first `all` will return an array.

Comment: We dont have a `Array#find` method. It is `Array#select`.

Comment: Hmm then why does this work? `arr = Model.all obj = arr.find {|x| x.id = 1}`. Am I confused or does `Model.all` not return an array?

Comment: sorry..you are right...there is [Enumerable#find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001484)..it returns first element satisying the condition in the enumerable..sorry..my bad

Comment: I was wondering why find worked, totally forgot about Enumerable.

Comment: me too forgot about Enumerable :P